# Java delete files of certain size

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I have a Java tool that generates 100,000+ files that I subsequently use in "Step 2" of my process.  Due to the nature of "Step 2", I don't want any files > 1MB.  Here was the code I was using to remove those files:

```
File[] files = root.listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        if (file.length > 1048576) { //size of MB
            //delete the file
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

This was working fine when the number of files was relatively small.  However, with n > 100,000 the call to listFiles() is crashing my system because of memory constraints.  I know you can filter results based on file type, but is there a way to do it based on file size?  Or, is there another way that I can easily do a large batch delete based on file size that won't crash my system?

FWIW, I'm running RedHat 6.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem comes from this part of the program? A File is just a path. So even if each of you file has a path which is 100 characters long, each taking 2 bytes in memory, and we round the size it uses to 250 bytes, 100,000 files would only cost 25 MBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is using the version of [`listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) that receives a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html), notice that in the [accept()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File%29) method you can ask the size of each file before returning the `File[]`, and only include the files that have the expected size. This has the advantage that only the files that need to be deleted will be returned.

Comment: He could do even better than that. He could delete the file if it's too big *in the accept() method* and always return false. Then the listFiles() result will be empty.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look at the [DirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html).  Like you'd expect, it lets you iterate over directory contents in a stream fashion, so you won't run out of memory from large directories:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dirPath)) {
   for (Path entry : stream) {
       File file = entry.toFile();
       if (file.isFile()) {
          if (file.length > 1048576) { //size of MB
             //delete the file
             file.delete();
          }
       }
   }
}
```

You might want to look at the source code for `Files#listFiles(FileFilter)`.  At least on my version (Java 1.7, Mac OS) it's implemented by calling `Files#list()` and then copying over all the matches, meaning it takes up *more* space in memory than `Files#list()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a FileFilter in File.listFiles that would only return the files you need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Apache Commons [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). The method that you may find useful is `FileUtils#iterateFiles(File directory,IOFileFilter fileFilter,IOFileFilter dirFilter)` ([javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29)). You can use a `IOFileFilter` ([javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html)) which will allow you to specify the size of the files that you want to accept while iterating.

Could it be that this is calling `listFiles()` under the hood? Absolutely. However you don't know till you try :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks `listFiles()` is exactly what `iterateFiles()` uses: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java?view=markup